# python flask-sqlalchemy - reuse function results multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.6

I've got two functions I use with a Route in Flask.  I use the results of the first function as the input for the second function.  However, I want to return the results for both functions, but instead, I'm only getting the results for the second function.  If I comment out function 2 (get_net_info()), the results for function 1(get_related_interfaces()) are passed to the render_template.

How can I return results for both?  (My ultimate goal is to return both results to the render_template command.)

Function 1:

```
def get_related_interfaces(ipAddr):
    if ipAddr:
        try:
            queryInt = text("SELECT * FROM ROUTER_INTERFACES WHERE ROUTER_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTION LIKE :ipa")
            queryInt = queryInt.bindparams(ipa="%" + ipAddr + "%")
            interfaces = db.engine.execute(queryInt)

            return interfaces

    except Exception as e:
        print("IP Interfaces Error")
        print(e)
```

Function 2:

```
def get_net_info(interfaces):
    if interfaces:
        try:
            for interface in interfaces:
                if interface.router_interface_ips:
                    candidateNet = ipaddress.IPv4Address(interface.router_interface_ips) + 1

                    return candidateNet

        except Exception as e:
            print("Net Detail Error")
            print(e)
```

Usage:

```
ipAddr = service_detail.ipAddr #192.168.0.1
interfaces = get_related_interfaces(ipAddr) #returns interfaces with ipAddr
candidateNet = get_net_info(interfaces) #returns candidateNet which is 192.168.0.2
print (candidateNet)

return render_template("service.html", interfaces=interfaces)
```

Result:

```
192.168.0.2 shows up in log(because of print statement) <-- This is what I wanted
interfaces is empty when returned to the template for rendering <-- Not what I want
```

Expected Result:

```
192.168.0.2 shows up in the log
AND
interfaces result is returned to the template for rendering
```

Comment: what happens when you ```print(interfaces)``` after printing candidateNet? Because it seems like interfaces can't be empty because it's successfully being used in the get_net_info function.

Comment: `db.engine.execute()` returns a `ResultProxy` object, and it behaves like an iterator, your best call may be to convert this into a list if you need to use it multiple times. You can apply `fetchall()` after the method `execute`

Comment: @PRMoureu That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon the suggestion of @PRMoureu, I added "fetchall() to the end of my query execute line like so:

```
interfaces = db.engine.execute(queryInt).fetchall()
```

I'm now getting the expected result above.  Thank you.